# View not attached to window manager in onAttachedToWindow

Tags: android

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
View not attached to window manager
```

This exception is thrown here:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
}
```

how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to finish an activity without closing the Dialog then this type of error will come.